# What is CPython's RNG seed set to for the random module?

Tags: python, random, random-seed

You can set Python's random number generator by calling `random.seed(theSeed)`. The subsequent random numbers generated from that seed are predictable. The following interactive shell example shows the same random numbers being generated from the integer seed `42` on Python 3.10.2:

```
>>> import random
>>> random.seed(42)
>>> [random.randint(0, 9) for i in range(20)]
[1, 0, 4, 3, 3, 2, 1, 8, 1, 9, 6, 0, 0, 1, 3, 3, 8, 9, 0, 8]
>>> random.seed(42)
>>> [random.randint(0, 9) for i in range(20)]
[1, 0, 4, 3, 3, 2, 1, 8, 1, 9, 6, 0, 0, 1, 3, 3, 8, 9, 0, 8]
```

But you don't have to call `random.seed()` before you start obtaining random numbers. What is the default seed used by CPython (the Python interpreter from python.org)?

Answer (score 3):

The default seed of the `random` module comes from the operating system's cryptographically secure random number generator (CSRNG) source (the same as `os.urandom()`). If this isn't available, the [fallback seed is made from the current system time and the Python interpreter's process ID](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e8e4b550f50e716c57cc5d0225042ab766c5582d/Modules/_randommodule.c#L284-L289). This means that CPython's seed isn't trivial to predict.